# React crashing when frequently receiving data from socket.io

Tags: browser, socket.io, next.js

I have a react app receiving data every 5 seconds. The server handles it fine, but if you leave the page and come back or wait ~10 seconds, the page will turn white and become unresponsive.

The data contains information for the app to update and display.

I've tried using an async function to process the data, but that doesn't help

socketio client code:

```
socket.on('UpdateGames', data => {
    const {j, s, e} = JSON.parse(data)
    setJoin(j.map(item => new Game(item)))

    setSpec(s.map(item => new Game(item)))

    setEnd(e.map(item => new Game(item)))
})
```

Edit: tried sending data every 10 seconds, but the same thing happens

Comment: There is nothing inherently difficult for react to receive a websocket message every 10 second. The problem is not directly related to this general setup, but in your code.

Comment: @Evert I attached the code

Comment: Also nothing here that inherently bad, but I'm suspecting that the `set*` functions might be from `useState`, and maybe you didn't write cleanup functions. The issue is probably in your react code.

Comment: Unrelated, your use of `map` is very weird. You probably want `setJoin(j.map(item => new Game(item))`

Comment: @Evert you're correct, I'm using useState, but what do you mean by cleanup functions. Also thanks for the correction on the map code, it was late when I wrote that, and didn't bother dejanking it.

Comment: Are you calling `socket.on()` for every render of your component? If so, every time you call `setEnd/setSpec` you will cause a re-render and you add _another_ subscription. So after 2 `UpdateGames` calls you have 2 subscriptions. After 10 calls, you have >1000 calls to `socket.on`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evert was correct that I didn't have any cleanup. Added this to my component

```
useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('connect', socket => {
        console.log('connected')
    })

    socket.on('UpdateGames', data => {
        const {j, s, e} = JSON.parse(data)

        console.log("RECEIVE")

        setJoin(j.map(item => new Game(item)))

        setSpec(s.map(item => new Game(item)))

        setEnd(e.map(item => new Game(item)))
    })
    

    return () => socket.off('UpdateGames', listener)
}, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

To add OP @COOKIE's answer, I found that

```
socket.removeAllListeners([eventName])
```

solved my issue of a weird recursive loop in my web app.

I believe this is because useEffect starts accruing socket listeners and this exponentially multiplies over time and crashes the web app.

See below for how I solved my issue:

```
useEffect(() => {
      socket.on(eventName, (res) => {
        func(res);
      });
      return () => socket.removeAllListeners(eventName);
    }
  }, [func, eventName]);
```

[See here for Socket IO docs on this function](https://socket.io/docs/v3/listening-to-events/#socketremovealllistenerseventname).